# Is it possible to create an NSSavePanel like the standard "keep this new document" dialog?

Tags: appkit, nssavepanel

In an application like TextEdit, if the user attempts to close a new document, a special NSSavePanel is displayed.

[image: example TextEdit dialog]

Is there any way that I can create an NSSavePanel that resembles this dialog? The only hook that I can find is the message string, but it is not obvious to me how a message string could include icons and formatting. Also, there is the special Delete button.

Comment: This save panel is created by `NSDocument` using private methods. A document based app automagically shows this panel when a dirty document window is closed.

Comment: For the panel look like this, you also need to return `true` for `autosavesInPlace` in your `NSDocument` subclass.